# Can't boot after misconfigured default display manager

Tags: boot, grub2, lightdm

First, I was stuck in a login loop on Ubuntu 20.04 and tried to reconfigure defaut display manager using

```
dpkg-reconfigure lightdm
```

Here, I might have changed the default display manager from (maybe: gdm) to lightdm and now I can't even boot to the login screen. I'm kicking myself because before this, I had access to the terminal and I could have just used TimeShift recovery. Now, I can't even boot normally and when I hold down Shift and tap Esc, I am directly kicked into GNU GRUB 2 without a chance for Recovery mode. Where do I go from here? Is there a way to gain back access to terminal or revert lightdm configurations?? Preferebly without a live CD/USB because I don't have access to one right now.

From the GNU Grub, I have also tried loading *kernal modules?* and some img and boot, but that also gets stuck at Adding/removing light display manager

Comment: You need the live CD.

Comment: you need the live cd. and install boot-repair
[https://launchpad.net/~yannubuntu/+archive/ubuntu/boot-repair][1]